# In case of pure rolling, does the formula $v=r\omega$ holds only for a small instant of time?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

For example, on a rough track when a ball rolls and is under smooth rolling, friction continues to act in the lower portion and so, torque acts along the centre of the ball. As per the formula:

$$\tau=I\dot{\omega}$$

Hence angular acceleration $\dot{\omega}$ must have some value.

Hence, pure rolling shall not be a permanent case on a rough track?

Comment: What is `smooth rolling`? Do you mean rolling without slipping? What does `torque acts along the centre of the ball` mean? Do you mean torque acting around the centre axis?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the figure below:

[image: Rolling friction.]

Let's say the ball is rolling with translational speed $v$ and angular speed $\omega$.

A friction force $F_f$ act on it as shown and the equation of translation is:

$$ma=-F_f$$

and using the simple model for friction:

$$F_f=\mu F_N= \mu mg,$$

with $\mu$ a friction coefficient.

So:

$$a=-\mu g$$

Assuming speed at $t=0$, $v=v_0$, then:

$$v=v_0-\mu gt$$

The force $F_f$ causes a torque about the centre of the ball, so the equation of rotation is:

$$\mu mgR=I\dot{\omega}$$

$$\dot{\omega}=\mu \frac{mgR}{I}$$

Assuming angular speed at $t=0$, $\omega =\omega_0$, then:

$$\omega=\omega_0+\mu \frac{mgR}{I}t$$

For pure rolling, no slipping:

$$v=\omega R$$

so:

$$v_0-\mu gt=\omega_0 R+\mu \frac{mgR^2}{I}t$$

Of course $v_0=\omega_0 R$, so we get:

$$\mu  +\mu \frac{mR^2}{I}=0$$

This gives us the critical friction coefficient $\mu_c$:

$$\large{\mu_c \geq \frac{I}{mR^2+I}}$$

This is the minimum friction coefficient $\mu$ needed to ensure pure rolling without slipping. One can fill in the value of $I$ for any rotating object (ball or cylinder, mainly)

Of course, in the spirit of the question, we assumed $v_0=\omega_0 R$. If that was not the case then $\mu_c$ has to be used in the equations of motion to calculate the time evolution of $v$ and $\omega$. After some time then $v=\omega R$ will be achieved.

Comment: $F_f=\mu F_N$ is only true during slipping. In general $F_f \le \mu F_N$. $$ $$ Your last equation is equivalent to $\mu_c + \mu_c\frac{mR^2}{I} \ge 1 $ which does not follow from your previous equations.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this wrong. Pure rolling occurs when there is **static friction** between the rolling surface and the ground.

Rolling resistance will occur when the wheel is not perfectly round relative to the track.

(exaggerated:)

[image]

When this is the case (slightly deformed wheel or not perfectly smooth track), some of the "friction" acts against the translational motion of the wheel (often referred to as slipping).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are asking about a static friction at the contact point with the surface, which will cause a torque. This torque will be unbalanced, so the ball should accelerate.

This is also perfectly correct *if* there was static friction at the contact point. But there is no such static friction when the surface is flat.

If the surface is tilted, then the weight tries to pull the ball to slide downwards, and here static friction *will* be present to prevent the ball from sliding at the contact point. In this case the torque from the friction is, as you correctly point out, indeed making the ball accelerate.

It will be clear, if you consider a snapshot in time of the situation. Zoom in around the contact point and ask yourself, if there are any forces sideways on the ball near this point. Only if there are such horizontal forces will the static friction be needed to balance them. On the tilted surface, the weight of the ball will have a horizontal (along with the slope) component, and therefore the static friction is appearing.

The point is that static friction in general can be anything between zero and some maximum value $f_s\le\mu n$. Static friction *only* takes a value, *if needed* to hold the object from sliding.